# factorization of polynomials in $ \mathbb F_7$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure in finding a factorization of $f(X) = 6 x^6 +1 \in \mathbb F_7$.

I got $f(X) =6\cdot (x-1)\cdot(x+1)\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x+2)\cdot(x-3)\cdot(x+3) $

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The easy version is noticing that $6=-1$, thus $$6x^6+1=-x^6+1$$ By Fermat's little theorem, $x^6-1$ has the six roots $1,2,3,4,5,6$ in $\Bbb F_7$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_7$ is a field, $f(a) = 0 \implies f(x) = (x-a)g(x)$  for some polynomial $g$

Comment: Thats a nice trick thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb{F}_7$ one has on one hand

$$\begin{align}
6x^6+1&=6(x^6-1)\\
&=6(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)\\
&=6(x-1)(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)
\end{align}$$

On the other hand

$$(x-2)(x+2)(x-3)(x+3)=(x^2-4)(x^2-2)=x^4-6x+8=x^4+x^2+1$$

So the factorisation is correct.